# TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array. with NaiveBayes Classifier

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, nltk, naivebayes

The Multinomial Naive Bayes Classifier is giving the correct result but the other two- The Gaussian NB and the Binomial NB are not. The error it gives is this:

> TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

But even on adding that function (`train_set.toarray()`) the error is

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toarray'

The code is

```
import pickle
from nltk.corpus import names
import random
import nltk
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB, GaussianNB, BernoulliNB
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier, LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc

def gender_features(word):
    return {'last_letter': word[-1]}

labeled_names = ([(name, 'male') for name in names.words('male.txt')] + [(name, 'female') for name in names.words('female.txt')])
random.shuffle(labeled_names)

featuresets = [(gender_features(n), gender) for (n, gender) in labeled_names]
train_set, test_set = featuresets[500:], featuresets[:500]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)*100)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)

MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(train_set)
print ("MNB classifier accuracy: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, test_set))*100)


G_classifier = SklearnClassifier(GaussianNB())
G_classifier.train(train_set)
print ("Gaussian classifier accuracy: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(G_classifier, test_set))*100)

B_classifier = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB())
B_classifier.train(train_set)
print ("Bernoulli classifier accuracy: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(B_classifier, test_set))*100)
```

Comment: The error says `train_set` is a list, not a sparse matrix.

Comment: Also, if you copied that error and not the code, you have a syntax error (`torray` =/ `toarray`)

Comment: @hpaulj Even on adding .toarray()it's showing error as said earlier. How to convert it into a sparse matrix?

Comment: @DanielF Why then, Multinomial is not showing the error but others are?

Comment: We need to know more about the `train_set` variable.  If a list, what do the elements look like?

Comment: You can try printing it. It's like "[({'last_letter': u'y'}, 'female'), ({'last_letter': u'n'}, 'female'), ({'last_letter': u'g'}, 'male'), ({'last_letter': u'n'}, 'female'), ({'last_letter': u'd'}, 'female'), .........."

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, while training try to use:

`train_set.todense()`

It worked for me:

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can do : numpy.array(train_set) ,make list to dense m